# building caffe with MKL

Tags: caffe, intel-mkl

Ran into two errors while building caffe with MKL. 
MKL is installed into /opt/intel

1. mkl.h not found
2. caffe usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_rt
3. /intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs

Answer (score 0):

The errors 1 & 2 were resolved after specifying the following two

```
BLAS := mkl
BLAS_INCLUDE := /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/mkl/include/
BLAS_LIB := /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/
```

For 3, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/402497

I had to add /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Also added /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.098/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.